# ASP.NET Connection Refused

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET C# Website, The website working on my friends pc (I made it there), but on my pc I get this error :

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:50160

I tried to disable the firewall but it didn't help.
I think that the problem can be fixed from the Web.config file, but I don't know how to fix it.
Any help ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your local loopback address. You need the address of your friends PC.

Comment: 127.0.01 is the local for all computers, I think that the problem is from the port, how can I solve it ? ( how can I change the port or check if it used from another program , or how to let the pc listen to that port ? @Dennis1679

Comment: If you are trying to access your friends computer by browsing to 127.0.0.1:50160, then the problem is that your are actually trying to access your own computer on port 50160, and because you have no HTTP service working on that port, you will get denied by your computer. So that being said, if you need to access your friends computers, go to the command line on your friends PC, type in `ipconfig` and see what his IP address is.

Comment: I've copied the website to my pc , and I get that error when I open it in my pc, how can I change the used port ? , if you know how to fix that can you connect to my pc using team viewer ? @Dennis1679

Comment: So let me get this clear, sorry for misunderstanding you. I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio. So you copied the project folder from your friends PC, and put it in the projects folder of Visual Studio. Then you run the application with F5 and it reads that No connection could be made? Is that what is happening?

Comment: Yep but not exactly, the project is working fine, but when I use the button that connected with the Web Service I get this error ...  @Dennis1679

Comment: I don't know what web service you are speaking about. Try and expand the question so that, maybe, I can help. It's very difficult to help you if your questions and your descriptions are a bit vague.

Comment: It's the same as you said , it's not an important note , the problem is like what you said @Dennis1679